# How can we query mongodb array of Objects ids?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a sub array which consists of object ids

```
 "selections" : ["5176d1f09de5ee2808028da9", "5176d1f09de5ee2808028e4d", "5176d1f09de5ee28080292fe", "5176d1f19de5ee2808029867"]
```

When users log in, these are registered using PHP sessions:

```
var_dump($selections);

array(16) { [0]=> string(24) "5176d1f09de5ee2808028a7c" [1]=> string(24) "5176d1f09de5ee2808029180" [2]=> string(24) "5176d1f09de5ee2808029283" [3]=> string(24) "5176d1f19de5ee280802990c"}
```

I get them from sessions and then use them in a query:

```
$selectionsFromSession= $_SESSION['selections'];

$list=$collection->find(array("_id"=>array('$in'=>  $selectionsFromSession )), ....
```

This query returns nothing.  What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate the MongoId Object.

```
foreach( $selections as &$selection ) {
    $selection = new \MongoId( $selection );
}
```

You then pass the array of instantiated objects to your query.

Comment: should I do it before registering to sessin or just before querying?

Comment: I think still returns empty

Comment: Try var_dumping the entire array being sent to your query. That is, the _id and $in included.

Comment: seems there is just one id passing to query var_dump($selection); object(MongoId)#19 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "5176d1f99de5ee2808030b59" }

Comment: You should be sending $selections, not $selection.